# Should containers for form fields extend UIView or UIControl?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I define custom fields for a form in classes such as `DropDownField` or `FooBarField`. These views/controls generally do not directly handle any interaction, but instead act as containers for other controls such as `UITextField`, along with showing labels, animations, validation code, etc.

Should `DropDownField` extend from `UIControl` or only from `UIView`?

I've provided minimal details because I'm primarily looking for a general explanation on when it's appropriate to subclass UIControl.

Comment: It's better that you subclass from UIControl in this case.

Comment: Hi Adeel, thanks for the comment but ideally could you give me an idea of when it's appropriate to use each? From looking at some open source apps, it seems common to extend UIView even for quite "control-ish" things... and Apple's `UITextView` does not extend from UIControl either.